# Handling identity column when managing SQL database table using external content type \ external list

Tags: external-content-type, external-list

I have a SQL table (with a primary key identity column) which I want to perform CRUD operations on using a SharePoint external list as a front end. I have setup stored procedures to perform the CRUD operations. I have been able to setup an external content type with Read Item, Read List, Update Item, and Delete Item operations.

I am having an issue with the Create operation. The identity column value gets set automatically when a row is inserted into the table. When I try to setup a Create operation on the external content type it wants the identity column to be explicitly specified by the user. I don't want the user to specify this identity - I want to to be automatically handled by SQL server when the new row is inserted.

Comment: If you edit the create operation in SP Designer I think there is an option to uncheck the column as an input parameter which, if I recall correctly, will default it to not being an editable column on your external list new item/edit item form.  If you are able to uncheck it but it shows up on the form as read-only, you can open up the new/edit forms in designer and hide the control.

Comment: I figured it out - the stored proc which performs the insert needs to return the identity column. You can then map the return value to the ID column on the external list.